# ASP.NET Core MVC & C# : insert data into database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to insert data from my ASP.NET Core MVC application with Entity Framework to my SQL Server database on localhost.

My model class looks like this:

```
public class Auto
{
    public string Motorleistung { get; set; }
    public string Lackierung { get; set; }
    public string Felgen { get; set; }
    public string Sonderleistungen { get; set; }
}
```

I already added the `DbContext` in a new folder (`Services/AutoContext` class):

```
public class AutoContext : DbContext
{
    DbSet<Auto> Autos { get; set; }

    public AutoContext(DbContextOptions<AutoContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

I added this part to the `Startup.cs` file in the `ConfigurateServices` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        var connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=Auto;User Id=sa;Password=YourPassword123";

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddDbContext<AutoContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
}
```

I am trying to use a class extension with a method to insert properties from auto into the DB:

```
public static class AutoContextExtensions
{
    public static void CreateSeedData(this AutoContext context)
    {
        var auto = new List<Auto>()
            {
                new Auto()
                {
                    Motorleistung = "500 PS",
                    Lackierung = "Gelb",
                    Felgen = "Chrome",
                    Sonderleistungen = "Sitzheizung"
                }
            };
        context.AddRange(auto);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I am now trying to call the `CreateSeedData` function from the `Startup.cs` to pass the data into my database like:

```
Projectname.AutoContextExtensions.CreateSeedData();
```

It expects me to give a parameter. What parameter do I have to pass? 
(I extracted the code from a sample)

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? If so please tell us exactly what it says.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The specific error I get is: you need to pass argument that fits the parameter "context" from             AutoContextExtensions.CreateSeedData();

Answer (score 1):

You need an instance of the context to be able to call the extension method.

There are more recommended ways to seed the database in EFCore

1- Use migrations to seed the data

> Then EF Core migrations can automatically compute what insert, update
>   or delete operations need to be applied when upgrading the database to
>   a new version of the model.

in OnModelCreating in the DBContext

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Auto>().HasData( new Auto()  {
                    Motorleistung = "500 PS",
                    Lackierung = "Gelb",
                    Felgen = "Chrome",
                    Sonderleistungen = "Sitzheizung"
                });
```

Then Add a new migration

2- Use seeding context

```
using (var context = new DataSeedingContext())
{
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();

    var testBlog = context.Blogs.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Url == "http://test.com");
    if (testBlog == null)
    {
        context.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://test.com" });
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

a Warning from the docs

> The seeding code should not be part of the normal app execution as
>   this can cause concurrency issues when multiple instances are running
>   and would also require the app having permission to modify the
>   database schema.

For more details check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding)  along with [full sample project](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/master/samples/core/Modeling/DataSeeding)

Answer (score 0):

CreateSeedData is an extension method for AutoContext type.But you are calling method like Projectname.AutoContextExtensions.CreateSeedData(); so you need to pass the parameter value of type autocontext. You should create a variable with  AutoContext type ,Then variablename.CreateSeedData() for extension method to work like you expect

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I create a new var of type auto context I get an error that i need to pass options parameter: AutoContext con = new AutoContext();

Comment: yes ,because Autocontext class have a constructor with options as argument=> public AutoContext(DbContextOptions<AutoContext> options)